# Angular not refreshing/changing values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

so first of all I wanna say that I'm using **socket.io** and emitting them with data. Data is emitted on connection (so website isn't blank) and when something happens. In this case, on connection (page refresh) everything updates and works great. When being on the site there are 2 issues :

- roundValue isn't updating real time, only on page refresh
- when `$scope.data.value` (value of doughnut chart) is increasing everything

works, but once I want to make it back to 0 and start over again it doesn't work. It starts blinking, getting data like 20times a second from new different values (so chart is changing from value 0-30 all the time, blinking).

My controller (last parts aren't important) :

```
.controller('KnobCtrl', ['$scope', 'mySocket', function($scope, mySocket) {
        $scope.itemsCounter = 0;
        $scope.roundValue = 0;

        mySocket.on('newConnectionCounter', function (itemsInRoundCounter, valueOfRound) {
            $scope.data.value = itemsInRoundCounter;
            $scope.roundValue = valueOfRound;
        });

        mySocket.on('addItemCounterIO', function(roundItems, valueofRound) {
            $scope.data.value = roundItems;
            $scope.roundValue = totalValue;
        });

        mySocket.on('newRoundCounter', function() {
            $scope.data.value = 0;
            $scope.roundValue = 0;
        });

        $scope.data = {
            value: 0,
            options: {
            width: 190,
            fgColor: "#FFAB40",
            skin: "tron",
            thickness: .3,
            displayPrevious: false,
            readOnly: true,
            max: 30,
                inputColor: "#ffffff"
        }
        };
        $scope.options = {
            width: 150,
            fgColor: "#ffec03",
            skin: "tron",
            thickness: .8,
            displayPrevious: false,
            readOnly: true,
            max: 50
        };

        $scope.formatOptions = function(data) {
            data.formattedOptions = JSON.stringify(data.options).replace(/,/g,"\n");
            return data;
        };
    }]);
```

Values on page aren't important I guess, they're just taking from `$scope.roundValue` and `$scope.data.value`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, the asynchronous events coming from socket.io do not trigger Angular's digest cycle. Normally, Angular's native $http, $timeout etc. services all automatically trigger the digest cycle. When you're using event sources that are foreign to Angular, you need to trigger the digest cycle yourself. Try calling `$scope.$digest()` in your socket.io event handlers, after updating the scope properties.

For example:

```
    mySocket.on('newConnectionCounter', function (itemsInRoundCounter, valueOfRound) {
        $scope.data.value = itemsInRoundCounter;
        $scope.roundValue = valueOfRound;
        $scope.$digest();
    });
```

Another flavour that will achieve the same thing:

```
    mySocket.on('newConnectionCounter', function (itemsInRoundCounter, valueOfRound) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.data.value = itemsInRoundCounter;
            $scope.roundValue = valueOfRound;
        });
    });
```

You could also use a wrapper like [angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) to get digest cycle triggering for free.

For the second problem you've mentioned, it's hard to tell without seeing how the mySocket service is implemented.

Comment: I tried both and none seems to update it unfortunately.
Here is how i implemented sockets (using btford.socket-io) http://codeshare.io/2LlkS